# Converting TIFF Image to XY Coordinates

Tags: python, image, dataframe, tiff

I am trying to deconstruct a TIFF image to XY coordinates in **Python**. The first column in dataframe should be X and second column as Y. A sample file is attached. Would it be done the same way as a JPEG? So far, I have tried the code below.

Sample Tiff Image:
https://file-examples.com/index.php/sample-images-download/sample-tiff-download/

Sample Code (can't figure out what I'm missing to get coordinates):

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
image= Image.open(r"file_example_TIFF_1MB.tiff")
mypixels= colourImg.convert("RGB")
colors = np.array(mypixels.getdata()).reshape(image.size + (3,))
```

Comment: FYI, uploading to imgur automatically converted your file to a png

Comment: OOPS! Yes, I can definitely add code, I don't know how I forgot to add it. And yes, I can add original image link as well. Sorry about that!

Comment: Hi @PranavHosangadi! Can you check if you are able to see the code and sample image? And then would really appreciate removing the -1. Thank you again for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`colors` is a `WxHx3` array. Let's look at `colors[:, :, 0]`, which is the red channel. The X coordinate is the column-index, and the Y-coordinate is the row index. To create the dataframe you want, you need to iterate over these.

```
result = []

h, w, _ = colors.shape
for x in range(w):
    for y in range(h):
        result.append([x, y, *colors[y, x, :]])
```

Then, create your dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=["X", "Y", "R", "G", "B"])
```

Alternatively, use `numpy.meshgrid()` to create the `x` and `y` numbers for you, and then flatten them into a column vector. This will be much faster than the loopy approach for larger images.

```
result = np.zeros((w * h, 5))
h, w, c = colors.shape

xg, yg = np.meshgrid(range(w), range(h))

result[:, 0] = xg.flatten()
result[:, 1] = yg.flatten()

for i in range(c):
   result[:, 2 + i] = colors[:, :, i].flatten()
```

Now you have the same thing as before in `result`, so you can convert it to a dataframe.

Comment: which packages do you import for 'colors.shape'?

Comment: `colors` is a numpy array, so you shouldn't need to import anything

Comment: is the 'df' inside the for loop with y in range(h)?

Comment: No, it's outside all loops. You want to create the dataframe _after you've finished all looping_

Comment: I think you are missing a closing parenthesis after the append statement. Also, when I run this, I get a index error:     result.append([x, y, *colors[y, x, :]])
IndexError: index 434 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 434

Comment: @sarah apologies, the order of `w, h` in `w, h = colors.shape` was flipped. It's been fixed now.

Comment: No Problem! Is there a way I can now 'reconstruct' the image using this df just to check if it has been properly converted?

Comment: @sarah use a smaller image (which is just a `WxHx3` array, e.g. use a `4x5x3` array `colors = np.arange(4*5*3).reshape((4, 5, 3))`) and verify each coordinate matches what you expect. Or reverse the loops.

Comment: Or reverse the loops, but then if your forwards logic and backwards logic has the same issue, you'll never know